# Copy Sql Server 2008 Databse schema only to Another Sql server 2008 Database on same machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Sql server 2008 Database

Is there any way to create new database and copy the schema of existing database objects to newly created database **using Sql query or Stored Procedure**

Comment: What's wrong with in SQL Server Management Studio: Right click on the database, Tasks, Copy Database?

Comment: But i want this thing dynamic so thats why i am not using sql server management studio

Comment: What's wrong with backup/restore (as a different name)?  Then you keep permissions too.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to make a full backup of the database you want to copy:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Database1
 TO DISK = 'X:\FullPath\AdvWorksData.bak'
   WITH FORMAT;
```

where `X:\FullPath` is the full path to a location you can backup to on disk.

Next you'll need to create the new database (if you haven't already):

```
CREATE DATABASE Database2;
```

And then finally you'll need to restore over the top of that database:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM Database1;

RESTORE DATABASE Database2
   FROM Database1
   WITH MOVE 'Database1_Data' TO 'X:\FullPath\Database2.mdf',
   MOVE 'Database1_Log' TO 'X:\FullPath\Database2.ldf';
GO
```

where `X:\FullPath` is the full path to where you're second databases files exist.

### Some Caveats

1. `MOVE 'Database1_Data'` and `'Database1_Log'` are the default **logical** file names. Those can differ. You can find those **logical** names under the properties of the database.
2. `'X:\FullPath\Database2.mdf'` and `'X:\FullPath\Database2.ldf'` may not both exist in the same location **and** can differ from the default locations. You can find those locations under the properties of the database.